# Is it possible to embed a game created with Unreal Engine into a flutter mobile application?

Tags: flutter, unreal-engine4

Is it possible to embed a game created using the unreal engine in a flutter application, so that once I open the flutter application, I can navigate to a particular page to start the game and also communicate between `flutter` app and the Unreal Engine game?

I found that its possible to embed unity in flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget. This is what I am looking for but with the Unreal Engine. Is it possible to do the same with the Unreal Engine?

Comment: I am also very interested in this question. Any answers?

Answer (score 1):

### I hate to be the bearer of bad news but...

...From the research I've done, no it isn't possible. The recommended way of doing game dev in Flutter is by using the [Flame game engine](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame). Unfortunately, the tutorial on the repo seems to be a bit outdated but [here's one that should be better](https://blog.geekyants.com/building-a-2d-game-in-flutter-a-comprehensive-guide-913f647846bc). However, [this](https://github.com/mogol/opengl_texture_widget_example) seems like a complex but potential solution to your problem, [here's](https://medium.com/@german_saprykin/opengl-with-texture-widget-f919743d25d9) the tutorial that the repo is based on.

To be clear, there is no native way to run UE games in Flutter

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.
https://github.com/BlzFans/FlutterUnreal

Flutter + Unreal, Integrate Flutter into Unreal Engine

Build Unreal game UI with Dart, Lua or Typescript

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qitqs.jpg)